# Looking to switch Main image with selected thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

all

I am currently making my own PHP-functional gallery, and all I need now is a javascript statement to switch the main image with the thumbnail image when clicked upon. I've tried several different codes, but each time I manage to somehow screw the whole thing up.

Here is a link to my JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/m6YMb/

I've tried using ID switching, but it wont seem to work with me, and I'm afraid it might interfere with other images in my website. :/

Here is extra code that I have implemented so far on my page:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var infoBox = document.getElementsByClassName("info");
            for (var i = 0; i < infoBox.length; i++) {
                infoBox[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if(e.style.display == 'block') {
                e.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                e.style.display = 'block';
            }
    }

    $(".heading").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active_heading")){
            $(".heading").removeClass("active_heading");
            $(this).addClass("active_heading");
        }    
    });
```

Hope you guys can help me out here, I'm still trying to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle example, just add $('#photo').attr('src', src);

`    $(document).ready(function() {

```
        $('#carouselv').jsCarousel({ 
            onthumbnailclick: function(src) { 
                alert(src);
                $('#photo').attr('src', src);
            }, autoscroll: false, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 3, orientation: 'v' 
        });
    }); `
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the src of the image.

```
$('#carouselv').jsCarousel({ 
    onthumbnailclick: function(src) { 
       document.getElementById('photo').src=src;
    }, autoscroll: false, masked: false, itemstodisplay: 3, orientation: 'v' 
});
```